# How to autostart daemontools on Opensuse

Tags: daemon, opensuse

I am trying to create daemon from script written in php.
My system is running OpenSuse 11.3 and has http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html installed from contrib package (http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.4:/Contrib/standard/x86_64/daemontools-0.76-1.2.x86_64.rpm)

The question is - how do I autostart svscanboot in OpenSuse?

Answer (score 1):

Add something like:
 SK:2345:respawn:/usr/bin/svscanboot
to the end of /etc/inittab

The SK prefix is just any unique 1-2char identifier.

Be aware that this method of starting daemons has issues if they depend on other services being available.